# HoverOut after transition

Tags: css

To witness the bug, hover on the right-side of the overlay box here (don't move your mouse even 1px after hovering):
http://jsfiddle.net/V99rf/

```
<style>
.container, .hoverMover {width:100px; height:100px; background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);}
.container {position:relative;}
.hoverMover {position:absolute; top:0; left:50px;}

.container:hover .hoverMover {background:green; left:0;}

.trans {-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hoverMover trans">
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that even after the dom element moves to the left, it remains green with a ":hover" being set.  This gets unset as soon as you move the mouse.  How do I make it unset when the dom element moves from under the mouse, even if the mouse isn't moved?

A recursive javascript timeout would be unsatisfying, but may be the only way...?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with an event, so you will need some sort of iterative loop to accomplish what you are looking for.